# Error receiving SOAP request values

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I'm receiving a SOAP request like this, but my service can´t load the values

```
<soapenv:Envelope
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<soapenv:Header
 xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
<soapenv:Body
 xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <Operation xmlns="http://www.schema.com/SoS"
   soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
...
```

But if I remove some of the requests tags, leaving only this 
everything works ok:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<soapenv:Header
 xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <doOperation
  soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
...
```

For an easier reading, I removed **xmlns="http://www.schema.com/SoS"** from Operation, **xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"** from soapenv:Envelope and **xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"** from soapenv:Body.